# regex to find tags within tags

Tags: php, preg-match

I am a newby to regex.
I wish to select everything between the block quotes but want to ignore the ones that have p tags in them.

Can someone please assist me?

The  the following can be found via preg_match()

```
<blockquote><a>this is a link</a><blockquote>
```

But not this

```
<blockquote><p><a>this is a link</a></p></blockquote>
```

Comment: don't use regex to parse html. it makes the unicorns sad

Answer (score 0):

As @Dagon commented, parsing HTML with Regular Expressions is a [Bad Idea™](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

That said, it is possible if we make a couple of assumptions:

- The `<p>` will **always** be **right** after the `<blockquote>` if it is present
- `<blockquote>`s will never be nested

We can then use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) to discount any matches that contain `<p>` by using the following regular expression: `/<blockquote>(?!<p>)(.*?)<\/blockquote>/`.

Comment: your assumptions are true, and ur regex is clean and simple for what I am about to do. But my only concern is, how do I capture them using parenthesis for using them as references for any kind of appending (as there already a couple of '()' in the regex already)

Comment: You can use `preg_match_all`, and the second match will contain what is inside the `<blockquote>`

Answer (score 0):

A clean way to do this is to use DOM with XPath.

If you want to use regex, you can try this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~<blockquote\b[^>]*>(?:[^<]+|(?R)|<(?!/(?:blockquote|p)>))*</blockquote>~';
```

It deals with nested blockquote tags and doesn't match if there is a p tag inside whatever its position.

Comment: it does work thanks, but my goal is to append something to whatever i find. preg_replace ( mixed $pattern , mixed $replacement , mixed $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int &$count ]] ). I need to use paranthessis in the regex to refer to them , for instance as $1 etc.